# How do I do this? Add a method to add one ingredient at a time (use a single String variable as the parameter. Do not pass it an array)

Tags: java, arrays, setter, getter

Disclaimer: I am new to programming so my code might be noobish. Anyway, I'm working on a reference data type class and one of the instructions says;

> Add a method to add one ingredient(I'm assuming to the ingredients array) at a time (use a single String variable as the parameter.  ***Do not pass it an array***).

the way I have it right now there is an array, but I cant quite figure out how to create this method with just a single string variable. Again I'm still very new to this.

P.S. the assignment is to create compliable reference  data type class not a running program(yet). There more to the code but this is the part I thought was most relevant.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


//default constructor
public class Recipe{
  private String recipeName="";
  private String [] ingredients = new String[20];
  private String [] instructions = new String[20];


public Recipe(){
   for(int i=0;i<ingredients.length;i++){
   recipeName="";
   ingredients[i]="";
   instructions[i]="";

   }
  }
 //getset recipeName
 public String getName(){
 return  recipeName;
 }
 public  void setName(String inName){
 recipeName = inName; 
 }
 //getset ingredients
 public String[] getIngredients(){
   return ingredients;
   } 
 public void setIngredients(String[] inIngredients){
     ingredients = inIngredients;
   }
```

Comment: You could pass it seperated with a comma for example. Afterwards you could split the string by the seperator. By the way javascript has nothing to do with java ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting Java code, please do *not* specify it as a Javascript snippet - and please format the code appropriately. (We don't know what IDE you're using, if any, but most provide a way of formatting the whole document simply.)

Comment: @KevinEsche: The method is meant to add *one* ingredient - there's no need to separate anything.

Comment: I suspect they want you to write an `addIngredient(String ingredient)` method. I suspect you want to keep a `List<String>` of ingredients rather than an array...

Comment: @JonSkeet oh you are right, didn´t read the question properly

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Shounds like a school exercise... so maybe he must use and array.

Comment: @Jkike: Hard to tell for sure, but the imports suggest that ArrayList is an option...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: but the constructor uses array... probably he can convert array to list and then back to array :) .We need to know the teacher to confirm this:D

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add ingredients one by one to your recipe and get the list of ingredients, the following should help.

```
private List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
...

public void setIngredients(String ingredient){
    ingredients.add(ingredient);
}

public List<String> getIngredients(){
    return ingredients;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your ingredients `array` to `ArrayList`

```
 private List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then create methods to add one ingredient to it:

```
public boolean addIngredient(String ingredient){
    return ingredients.add(ingredient);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can use arrayList which are better, but if you must use array:

```
public void addIngredient(String ingredient){
    for(int i=0; i<ingredients.length;i++){
      if("".equals(ingredients[i])}{
             ingredients[i]=ingredient;
             return; //no need to add more than once
        }
     }
}
```